# Are there any plans to make private Stack Exchange sites for university courses?

Tags: discussion, area-51

The current software that is in use by more and more universities for the purpose of questions & answers in courses is Piazza. Unfortunately, this software has a broken search capability, and is otherwise clunky (such as not allowing multiple student answers).

I think the Stack Exchange system could work very well for courses, and I wonder if the company has any plans to move into the area of education.

Comment: Unlikely I think. Though there is this: [Stack Overflow clones](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-overflow-clones)